# How to force join type for DBIx::Class ORM?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have code:

```
$self->search_related( 'Servers', {
    'Servers.active' => 'yes',
    'Ips.state'      => 0,
},{
    join => { Subnets => 'Ips' }
})->as_query;
```

which produces:

```
SELECT "me"."id", "me"."active", "me"."ip_id", "me"."locality_id", "me"."hostname", "me"."ca_certificate", "me"."openvpn_static_key", "me"."l2tp_key", "me"."description", "me"."notes" 
FROM "servers" "me" 
LEFT JOIN "subnets" "Subnets" ON "Subnets"."server_id" = "me"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "ips" "Ips" ON "Ips"."subnet_id" = "Subnets"."id" 
WHERE ( ( "Ips"."state" = ? AND "Servers"."active" = ? AND "me"."locality_id" = ? ) )
```

I may rewrite this code by:

```
$self->search_related( 'Servers', { active => 'yes' } )
  ->search_related( 'Subnets' )
  ->search_related( 'Ips', { state => 0 } )
  ->as_query
```

Which will produce:

```
SELECT "Ips"."id", "Ips"."subnet_id", "Ips"."ip", "Ips"."package_id", "Ips"."state", "Ips"."notes" 
FROM "servers" "me"  
JOIN "subnets" "Subnets" ON "Subnets"."server_id" = "me"."id"  
JOIN "ips" "Ips" ON "Ips"."subnet_id" = "Subnets"."id" 
WHERE ( ( "active" = ? AND "me"."locality_id" = ? AND "state" = ? ) )
```

But is there a way for first case force `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: There is some useful information in https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Relationship

Answer (score 0):

The join type is defined by the relationship in your DBIC schema.
When you need a different join type for a search it is recommended to just define another relationship with this join type, e.g. `has_many('Subnets_full_join', ...)` and use this in the search instead of the regular one.